# Structural Equation Modeling with ordinal dependent variable in Stata

Tags: categorical-data, stata, structural-equation-modeling

I am analysing a data looking at the associations between BMI, body image concerns, depression, and breastfeeding: body image and depression are latent variables and they are mediators. Breastfeeding (months) is the dependent variable, and I want it to be ordinal (5 categories: 0, <3. <6, <12, <18).

I use Stata and below is my syntax:

```
gsem ///
(ee638 ee639 ee640 ee641 ee642 ee643 ee644 ee645 <-Depression) ///
(ee925 ee927 ee929 ee931 <-BI) ///
(Depression <- BI dif_bmi) ///
(BI <- dif_bmi) ///
(i.bf_dur <- BI Depression dif_bmi)
```

I wonder if the last line (i.bf_dur) is correct to handle ordinal dependent variable. I found a paper suggesting (i.bf_dur <- BI Depression dif_bmi, ologit), but I am not sure which is correct.

Any advice would be really appreciated.
Thx!